# What is going on with this html5lib script?

Tags: python, html5lib

Trying to process a very simple html5 script and render it using html5lib

```
import html5lib

html = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="a.js"></script>
        <script src="b.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
'''

parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree = html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"))
walker = html5lib.treewalkers.getTreeWalker("lxml")
serializer = html5lib.serializer.htmlserializer.HTMLSerializer()

document = parser.parse(html)
stream = walker(document)
theHTML = serializer.render(stream)

print theHTML
```

The output looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head>
        <title>Hi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src=a.js></script>
        <script src=b.js></script>
```

Yup. It just cuts off mid way. Changing the tree builder from lxml to dom does nothing. Tweaking the HTML changes the output but it's still pretty corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the key seems to be `omit_optional_tags=False` somehow with that missing it eats the end of the output.

```
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree = html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"))
document = parser.parse(html)    
walker = html5lib.treewalkers.getTreeWalker("lxml")
stream = walker(document)
s = serializer.htmlserializer.HTMLSerializer(omit_optional_tags=False)
output_generator = s.serialize(stream)
for item in output_generator:
         print item


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>


<title>
Hi
</title>


</head>


<body>


<script src=a.js>
</script>


<script src=b.js>
</script>




</body>
</html>
>>>
```

Comment: Well unable to reproduce using your code. 's' isn't even defined in your code. Want to edit your response with code that doesn't error?

Comment: Ah. So the key seems to be omit_optional_tags=False -- somehow with that missing it eats the end of the output.